# Passing SQL Server exception to .net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception

Stored procedure :

```
Procedure GetLocalConfig
(
    @ConfigId int
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT 1/0
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  


     IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN 
END CATCH
```

.Net code calling the Stored Procedure :

```
try
{
return DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConnectionStringConfigName)
       .ExecuteSprocAccessor(DbCommands.GetLocalConfig, new LocalConfigDtoMapper(), configId)
       .Single();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // Exception : Sequence contains no elements???
}
```

If I execute this SP from SSMS I get the actual exception :

```
ErrorNumber ErrorSeverity ErrorState  ErrorProcedure ErrorLine   ErrorMessage
8134        16            1           GetLocalConfig 54           Divide by zero error encountered.
```

I would like to see this exception in my try catch block for .Net however I keep getting Sequence contains no elements.

After some research I found I could RAISEERROR inside my stored procedure Try catch block :

```
DECLARE @errnum nchar(5), @errmsg nvarchar(2048);
SELECT
   @errnum = RIGHT('00000' + ERROR_NUMBER(), 5),
   @errmsg = @errnum + ' ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
RAISERROR (@errmsg, 16, 1);
```

Now when I run the SP using SSMS I get :

> *Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetLocalConfig, Line 70
>
>   8134  Divide by zero error encountered.*

But still .Net is giving me the same exception, how do I get the exception to be passed over to .Net in this case?

Comment: If you suppress the exception in TSQL, how will it get back to the caller?

Comment: So the solution would be to just use Command object and ExecuteReader and then I would see the exception?

Comment: Even if I handle the .Single() condition with .Any() check I am still not going to see the exception.

Comment: Remove the `Single()` from you linq and see what `ExecuteSprocAccessor(DbCommands.GetLocalConfig, new LocalConfigDtoMapper(), configId)` actually returns. Without knowing more about your data access layer I am unable to help.

Comment: So I put a check for .Any() before the .Single() and it quietly passes the ExecuteSprocAccessor and goes to the check and returns null, no exceptions.

Comment: got it, its the TRY CATCH which is suppressing the error as you pointed out earlier, in this case since I'm rolling back the transaction, whats the best way to Roll Back transaction if there is an exception ? (this same template for try catch is used in multiple places while doing inserts and updates where I actually need the rollback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the error row you return from the `GetLocalConfig` SP does not map using the `LocalConfigDtoMapper`, its expecting a different schema.

Therfore you suppress the actual exeption, and return a row with the wrong schema. This results a zero length sequence or empty enumerable being returned to the caller. When the `Single()` check asserts that you have one row only, it throws the appropriate exception because you have none.

---

If you want to rollback on error look at these duplicates

[How to rollback a transaction in TSQL when string data is truncated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639238/how-to-rollback-a-transaction-in-tsql-when-string-data-is-truncated)

[SQL Server 2008 Transaction, rollback required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997271/sql-server-2008-transaction-rollback-required)

[SQL Server - transactions roll back on error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749719/sql-server-transactions-roll-back-on-error)

Essentialy

You can re raise the error with [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) in your `CATCH` block. You  can get the original "exception" details with the [`ERROR_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx)... functions

or

[`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)

Comment: I just added the answer above.Thanks !

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi, why? seems to be a reiteration of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The TRY CATCH block inside the SP was suppressing the actual error message, removing the that I get the actual exception in my application.